# How do I solve a recurrence relation with multiple conditions?

Tags: recurrence-relations, wolfram-alpha

Suppose I have a recurrence relation like :

\begin{equation}
  f(n)=\begin{cases}
    2*f(n-1)  , & \text{n%2 = 1}.\\
    f(n-1) + 1, & \text{n%2 = 0}.
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
f(0) = f(1) = 1
\end{equation}

How would I go about solving this? What do you call such a recurrence relation?

Is there a way I can get $f(n)$ that will solve it for both cases?

I tried using the WolframAlpha [RSolve](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RSolve.html?q=RSolve) function and tried to use [Mod](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Mod.html) to write a single equation hoping it could solve it. But it kept throwing a syntax error.

I am fine even if you provide a solution using WolframAlpha.

Comment: The actual equation is slightly more complex, this is just a simplified example.

Comment: For anyone wondering % is the mod symbol.

Comment: What happened to the answer? Someone wrote an answer and deleted it.

Comment: I'm sorry about that. However, I had made a mistake in my calculations of the values and, thus, had the wrong recursion formula. Thus, I temporarily deleted my answer until I had a chance to correct the values and determine the appropriate new equations before undeleting the answer so it can be viewed. For now, I've not provided the proof of the 2 equations as it's a relatively simple induction problem, but I might add it later.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this type of problem has a special name. It's just basically a function definition split between $2$ different types of values, in this case depending on whether $n$ is odd or even.

The way I would approach trying to solve these types of problems is to determine the first few values to see if I can find any pattern and, if so, then I will try to prove it, usually by using some form of induction.

You're given
\begin{equation}
  f(n)=\begin{cases}
    2*f(n-1)  , & \text{n%2 = 1}.\\
    f(n-1) + 1, & \text{n%2 = 0}.
  \end{cases} \tag{1}\label{eq1}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
f(0) = f(1) = 1
\end{equation}

The next few values are:
\begin{align}
f(2) & = f(1) + 1 = 2 \\
f(3) & = 2 \times f(2) = 4 \\
f(4) & = f(3) + 1 = 5 \\
f(5) & = 2 \times f(4) = 10 \\
f(6) & = f(5) + 1 = 11 \\
f(7) & = 2 \times f(6) = 22 \\
f(8) & = f(7) + 1 = 23
\end{align}

Since $f(n)$ is defined separately for odd & even $n$, it's likely the values for $f(n)$ would have somewhat separate patterns for odd & even values of $n$. In this case, the pattern for even $n$ seems a bit simpler, with the odd $n$ being just one less than the even $n + 1$ value. The even $n$ have $f(0) = 1$, $f(2) = 2$, $f(4) = 5$, $f(6) = 11$ and $f(8) = 23$. It's not immediately obvious, at least it wasn't for me, but for $n \ge 2$, the value is the sum of power of $2$ and the next smaller power of $2$, then less 1, with the powers of $2$ increasing by $1$ each time. In particular,

$$f(n) = 2^{n/2} + 2^{(n-2)/2} - 1 \; \text{ for } \; n \ge 2, n \, \% \, 2 = 0 \tag{2}\label{eq2}$$

Note this equation doesn't apply to $n = 0$, as it gives a result of $f(0) = \frac{1}{2}$. This is because the initial value of $f(1) = 1$ doesn't behave according to \eqref{eq1} since it gives $f(1) = 2 \times f(0) = 2$ instead.

From the recursion formula for odd $n$ being one less than the function for $n + 1$ (which is even), you get,

$$f(n) = f(n+1) - 1 = 2^{(n+1)/2} + 2^{(n-1)/2} - 2 \; \text{ for } \; n \ge 1, n  \, \%  \, 2 = 1 \tag{3}\label{eq3}$$

You can prove \eqref{eq2} and \eqref{eq3} by using strong induction. For $n = 1$, \eqref{eq3} gives $f(1) = 2^1 + 2^0 - 2 = 2 + 1 - 2 = 1$. For $n = 2$, \eqref{eq2} gives $f(2) = 2^1 + 2^0 - 1 = 2 + 1 - 1 = 2$. This proves the base cases. Assume \eqref{eq2} and \eqref{eq3} hold for all $n \le k$ for some $k \ge 1$. For $n = k + 1$, if $n$ is even, then \eqref{eq1}, along with \eqref{eq3} for $f(n-1)$, gives $f(n) = f(n - 1) + 1 = \left(2^{n/2} + 2^{(n - 2)/2} - 2\right) + 1 = 2^{n/2} + 2^{(n - 2)/2} - 1$, which matches \eqref{eq2}. If $n$ is odd instead, then \eqref{eq1}, along with \eqref{eq2} for $f(n-1)$, gives $f(n) = 2 \times f(n - 1) = 2 \times \left(2^{(n-1)/2} + 2^{(n-3)/2} - 1\right) = 2^{(n+1)/2} + 2^{(n-1)/2} - 2$, which matches \eqref{eq3}. Thus, this proves the inductive step, confirming that \eqref{eq2} and \eqref{eq3} are valid for all $n \ge 1$.

Update: I read some of the Wolfram-Alpha documentation to figure out how to use it. However, I didn't see any way to use a function definition split as done here. Nonetheless, I was able to use the Mod function to express it in one equation, so the expression I used was

> RSolve[{f[n]==(2^Mod[n,2])f[n-1] + Mod[n-1,2],f[1]==1},f[n],n]

Note I only gave it $f(1)$ as $f(0)$ doesn't follow from the formula (when I also gave it $f(0)$, it failed to do the calculations). The results are [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=RSolve%5B%7Bf%5Bn%5D%3D%3D(2%5EMod%5Bn,2%5D)f%5Bn-1%5D+%2B+Mod%5Bn-1,2%5D,f%5B1%5D%3D%3D1%7D,f%5Bn%5D,n%5D). It produced just one equation of

$$f(n) = 2^{\lfloor(n - 1)/2\rfloor - \lfloor(n - 2)/2\rfloor}\left(3 \times 2^{\lfloor(n - 2)/2\rfloor} - 1\right) \tag{4}\label{eq4}$$

For even $n$, $2^{\lfloor(n - 1)/2\rfloor - \lfloor(n - 2)/2\rfloor} = 2^{(n-2)/2 - (n-2)/2} = 2^0 = 1$ and $3 \times 2^{\lfloor(n - 2)/2\rfloor} - 1 = (2 + 1) \times 2^{(n - 2)/2} - 1 = 2^{n/2} + 2^{(n-2)/2} - 1$, so it matches \eqref{eq2}. For odd $n$, $2^{\lfloor(n - 1)/2\rfloor - \lfloor(n - 2)/2\rfloor} = 2^{(n-1)/2 - (n-3)/2} = 2^1 = 2$ and $3 \times 2^{\lfloor(n - 2)/2\rfloor} - 1 = (2 + 1) \times 2^{(n-3)/2} - 1 = 2^{(n-1)/2} + 2^{(n-3)/2} - 1$, so the product of the $2$ parts gives \eqref{eq3}. In my opinion, it's mainly a matter of choice as to whether it's better to have $2$ simpler equations like I do or just one somewhat more complicated equation, like Wolfram-Alpha produces.

Comment: You have solved it for a specific case. Is there a way to extend this to a more complex version ? Any way to solve an equation like this on Wolfram Alpha ?

Comment: In general, even for more complex versions, I would still follow the same basic steps, i.e., calculate a few values to see if there's any pattern. However, note that for many cases, even some more complex versions will not have a closed-form solution. As for solving an equation like this on Wolfram-Alpha, I rarely use it and don't know much about it. I suggest reading its documentation of its available functionality to see if there's anything which might work and, if so, then try it to confirm.

Comment: @AkshayLAradhya In my comment above, I meant to write that even some only slightly more complex versions may not have a closed-form solution. Also, as you can see, I've added a proof by strong induction. Finally, as for Wolfram-Alpha, I just checked the RSolve documentation you linked to. I believe it could possibly solve problems like yours as it supports a system of recurrence equations. However, I haven't checked the details to confirm this. As for using Mod, that should work. What sort of syntax error were you getting? I'm a very experienced computer programmer so perhaps I could help.

Comment: @AkshayLAradhya As you can see from my updated solution, I was able to use Wolfram-Alpha to solve this. Regarding the error you were getting, I found Wolfram couldn't solve the problem if I provided $f(0) = 1$ to it, likely because it doesn't follow the provided equation. If this isn't the error you got, please check what I provided to Wolfram to see how it differs from what you tried.

Comment: When I try to put my equation it gives me this error : `For some branches of the general solution, unable to compute the limit at the given points. Some of the solutions may be lost.`. Nevermind tanks for your effort though.Appreciate it. I guess Ill just treat them as 2 separate equations and go forward with that.

Comment: You can try this `RSolve[{f[n+1]== Mod[n,2]*(f[n] + 2) ,f[1]==1},f[n],n]` I just dosent seem to be able to solve it.

Comment: @AkshayLAradhya As for your other equation, note Wolfram-Alpha actually **does** solve it, but just doesn't give you a formula for it, likely because there's no single formula in closed form. However, as you can see from it's plot, plus you can confirm by checking the initial sets of values, $f(1) = 1$, $f(2) = 3$, then it alternates, with $f(n) = 0$ for $n$ odd & $n \ge 3$, and with $f(n) = 2$ for $n$ even & $n \ge 4$. This is because for $n$ odd, Mod$(n-1,2) = 0$ so $f(n) = 0$, while for $n$ even, Mod$(n-1,2) = 1$ but $f(n-1) = 0$, so $f(n) = 1 \times (0 + 2) = 2$.

Answer (score 0):

Refer this link : [Codeforces](https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/53202) and check Yeputons' second answer(the part where he breaks the solution). Has a nice way of breaking the function into two different functions. Maybe you can proceed with it.